# How do I know what size ice axe I should get?

Tags: gear, mountaineering, ice-axes

I'm going to start mountaineering. Is there a recommended size per height/weight for ice axes for general mountaineering?

Comment: There is no single best length for an ax, even for a particular person. A long one is good for walking in cane position on a relatively low-angle slope. As the slope gets steeper and you start getting into something more like ice climbing, you want a shorter ax or technical ice tools. Lengths of axes don't really correlate much with the person's size. It's more about what activity you're going to be doing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With your hand on top of the head of the axe and holding it down by your side, the spike should come down to about your ankle. This will feel quite short, but when walking on steep ground (which you should be when taking an axe!), holding the axe in your uphill hand it will be a very useful length. Shorter is also lighter...

Ideally try and borrow one and see how you get on.

Comment: Also worth noting that the angle of the ice you're ascending MAY impact your decision. The above advice is generally good enough, though, as a few centimeters differences won't mean much usually.

Comment: For steep mountaineering the above is absolutely true. The biggest reason for the short length is dexterity at steep grades and during a self arrest. Remember that the ice axe is not a walking stick, it is a tool for cutting steps in ice, and saving your life during a fall. Long ice axes will get in the way of both of these things.

Comment: I think considering an ice axe on its merits as a walking pole is probably the wrong idea. Surely, this has some value, but it doesn't address the question of how long an ice axe should be to serve its intended purpose, and do so as efficiently and as safely as possible... And once one is aware of these factors, he or she can choose to trade them for convenience as they please, but at least doing so with the knowledge of what it is they are exchanging.

Comment: According to https://www.outdoorgearlab.com/topics/snow-sports/best-ice-axe/buying-advice#length it should *not* come down to the ankle. That is the absolute *maximum* length it should be.

Answer (score 9):

Some people prefer to have one long enough to use as a short walking stick. Others prefer to save weight and go as short as possible. In any case, it should be long enough so that *you* can use it properly to self-arrest. Everything else is optional.

You could rent a couple of ice axes of different sizes, go out to a steep snowy slope, and practice self-arrests to see what you're comfortable with. The practice will be valuable in itself. Keep in mind that stopping in powder, ice, and deep slush are all different experiences.

Comment: +1 for `short walking stick`. In mixed terrain(hiking + some ice + some climbing) it's so much nicer to know you can self arrest just if.

Answer (score 7):

This is sourced from REI's [How To Choose An Ice Axe](http://www.rei.com/expertadvice/articles/ice+axe.html).

As Chris mentioned, the axe should barely touch the ground when standing upright and with arms at the side. A rough guide to ice axe length is:

- <5'8" (<1.72m): 50-60cm
- 5'8"-6'0" (1.72-1.8m): 60-70cm
- >6'0" (>1.8m): 60-70cm

Too short is generally better than too long.

As AA Grapsas commented, it also depends on the type of climbing. Axes less than 60cm are generally for technical ice climbing and are best used for very steep or vertical slopes. Since they're shorter, they don't offer much leverage and are therefore bad for self arrest.

On the same note, axes over 70cm are generally too long for technical climbing, but better used for flat or lower angle slopes.

Answer (score 6):

They say a picture is worth thousand words:

[image]

Generally (except activities like drytooling /ice climbing) when standing upright and holding the axe you should have the end of it in middle of the length of your calf.
[image]

Source: [Axe buying guide (Polish)](http://8a.pl/8academy/jak-wybrac-czekan-turystyczny-dobor-dlugosci/)

Answer (score 5):

Mountaineering ice axes serve a few simple functions: self-arrest, belay, and T-anchor. (And occasionally cutting steps, but hopefully by the time you're doing that, you will already know what you like.)

For belay and T-anchors, any length of axe is fine.

For self-arrest, however, there are some factors you could consider:

- In self-arrest, you are supposed to "fall" on the axe and use your body weight to dig it into the slope for a good arrest. If the shaft is too short, much of your weight will go directly on the snow instead of on the axe, reducing the weight on the axe, and therefore its stability against the shear force pulling it tangential to the slope.
- When dropping flat on your axe in self-arrest, the length of the shaft can affect how easy or hard it would be for you to self-impale. There are two common ways to impale yourself on the shaft in self arrest:

  1. If the shaft is too *short*, and in your self-arrest drop the pick didn't go right in and the bottom of the shaft is sticking up, it could go right into your abdomen. This is fairly uncommon.
  2. if the shaft is too *long*, and in your self-arrest the pick didn't go right in and the bottom of the shaft is sticking up, it could go go through your thigh. The poking angle required for this to happen can be much lower than that required for the first abdominal impalement...

So in summary, I find that (regardless of walking-stick usefulness) the best shaft length is the one between too long that it can impale my thighs, and too short that it can impale my abdomen. I generally measure this length as the diagonal from one shoulder to the hip bone on the opposite side, but you might find that this measurement varies for you.

Answer (score 4):

To add a data point to the curve, I'm 6'3", and after much deliberation bought a 65cm [DMM Cirque](http://dmmclimbing.com/products/cirque/) as a general winter hillwalking axe.

While I'm generally very happy with it, I'd definitely switch to a 60cm one next time. The only place where I find the extra length useful is cutting steps in descent.

Self-arrests with it are fine, but a shorter axe would be more wieldy for them.

Answer (score 0):

Always opt for shorter rather than longer. If you're holding the ice axe at your side with your arm extended, the bottom (spike) should be just below the middle of your calf. If it reaches your ankle, it's way too long.

The general advice used to be that an ice axe should never be longer than reaching your ankle, but somehow that turned into that it should reach your ankle. If an ice axe can be used as a walking stick, it's not going to be much use on steeper slopes - which is when you actually need it to self-arrest.

I wrote an article for AlpInsider on [how to use an ice axe](https://www.alpinsider.com/guides/how-to-use-an-ice-axe), which explains more about why shorter is better for self-arresting and how to actually use your axe. As a data point, I'm 5'11 and use a 54cm axe with a curved shaft, so it comes to about mid-way between the top of my calf and my ankle bone.

Comment: Hey Michael, welcome to TGO! Thanks for mentioning your connection/vested interest in promoting the article. In order to make your answer a bit more complete please considering adding a summary of some of the key points from your article about why shorter is better for self-arresting in your answer.

Comment: Also I would like to challenge the "shorter is better" claim based on my experience with ice axes from 66cm to 45cm at a body height of 1,80m. A short ice axe is useless in the lower steepness terrain. A longer ice axe can still be used well in 45° terrain. If you go considerably steeper one would take an ice tool anyways, but this is no longer general mountaineering and definitely not in the scope of a beginner.